# Process server callback data in PHP

Tags: php, html, json, codeigniter

I'm having some trouble processing a callback that is being sent from a service I'm using for my app (http://Cameratag.com).

I am simply trying to take the data being sent from Cameratag and do things with it.

Below is a "test" script that I am trying to get to work.. But am having a terrible time trying to find out what is not working.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Process_video_test extends CI_Controller {
function __construct()
 { 
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('email');

 }

public function index()
 {
    $raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($raw, true);

    $uuid = $json["uuid"];

    $this->email->from('Senders@email.com', 'Senders Name');
    $this->email->to('Recievers@email.com'); 
    $this->email->subject($uuid);
    $this->email->message($uuid);   
    $this->email->send(); 

 }
}
```

When I resend the data to this script, nothing happens. Even when you visit or curl the url of this script, it sends out a blank email. I get nothing when I re-send the callback.

The callback server is definitely POSTing the data too, I can find following in my server logs:

```
54.224.22.73 - - [09/Oct/2013:07:07:50 -0500] "POST /process_video_test?uuid=59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6&camera_uuid=732c58e0-ea3f-0130-73d4-22000aecbdd8&created_at=2013-09-16%2022%3A50%3A47%20UTC&percent_complete=100&short_code=eMOhvg&metadata[email]=Coeyman%40gmail.com&state=published&recorded_from=http%3A%2F%2Fjordan.crowdengage.com%2F&publish_type=webcam&formats[][name]=vga&formats[][width]=640&formats[][height]=480&formats[][video_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fvga%2Fmp4&formats[][mp4_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fvga%2Fmp4&formats[][webm_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fvga%2Fwebm&formats[][thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fvga%2Fthumb&formats[][small_thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fvga%2Fsmall_thumb&formats[][state]=COMPLETED&formats[][completed_at]=2013-09-16%2022%3A51%3A57%20UTC&formats[][name]=360p&formats[][width]=480&formats[][height]=360&formats[][video_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2F360p%2Fmp4&formats[][mp4_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2F360p%2Fmp4&formats[][webm_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2F360p%2Fwebm&formats[][thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2F360p%2Fthumb&formats[][small_thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2F360p%2Fsmall_thumb&formats[][state]=COMPLETED&formats[][completed_at]=2013-09-16%2022%3A51%3A58%20UTC&formats[][name]=qvga&formats[][width]=320&formats[][height]=240&formats[][video_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fqvga%2Fmp4&formats[][mp4_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fqvga%2Fmp4&formats[][webm_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fqvga%2Fwebm&formats[][thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fqvga%2Fthumb&formats[][small_thumbnail_url]=http%3A%2F%2Fcameratag.com%2Fvideos%2F59fbe950-0150-0131-7bd6-22000a8fabd6%2Fqvga%2Fsmall_thumb&formats[][state]=COMPLETED&formats[][completed_at]=2013-09-16%2022%3A51%3A56%20UTC HTTP/1.1" 403 18156 "-" "-"
```

---

EDIT:

I tried the following code as my index file:

class Process_video_test extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index() 
 {
    $debug_me = 1;

    $raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($raw, true);

    if ($debug_me) {
        ob_start();
        var_dump('raw:', $raw, 'json:', $json);
        log_message('info', ob_get_contents());
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

In my log file is the following:

```
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Config Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Router Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Output Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Input Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Language Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Loader Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Helper loaded: utility_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> Helper loaded: menu_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Config file loaded: application/config/ion_auth.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Email Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Language file loaded: language/english/ion_auth_lang.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Helper loaded: cookie_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Helper loaded: language_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Session Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Helper loaded: string_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> A session cookie was not found.
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Session routines successfully run
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Model Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Helper loaded: date_helper
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> REST Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> cURL Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Controller Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> File loaded: application/views/includes/header.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> File loaded: application/views/landing.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> File loaded: application/views/includes/footer.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> File loaded: application/views/includes/template.php
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:13 --> Total execution time: 0.3939
```

Comment: You can `var_dump($raw)` and `var_dump($json)` to see is it correct data or not. Also. per server's log record, I see that `uuid` is GET variable not POST.

Comment: Maybe I wrong, of course, but with default settings Apache not shows POST data in the log. So if you see `uuid` here it is GET['uuid'].

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `var_dump`, I don't see the page through my browser to see the results. 

I tried `$uuid = $_GET["uuid"];` and it had no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 0. Make sure your class was called

As I see from logs: `DEBUG - 2013-10-09 10:01:12 --> No URI present. Default controller set.`. It means `Process_video_test` was not loaded for runnig. Also, just saw from server's log: `*.*.*.* - - [09/Oct/2013:07:07:50 -0500] "POST /process_video_test?*** HTTP/1.1" 403 18156 "-" "-"`. It means, your 3rd party has received HTTP error `403 Forbidden`. Looks like your server returns 403 error and do not loads `/process_video_test` URL

### Step 1. Enable logging

Open `application/config/config.php` file and set `log_threshold` parameter to the `3` (Informational Messages):

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 3;
```

Make sure that `log_path` parameter set to `''` and check where is your log file stored by default (just read comment above `log_path` in your `config.php`, which is headed by "Error Logging Directory Path").

```
$config['log_path'] = '';
```

For example, in CodeIgniter 2.1.4 default log file location is `application/logs/`.

### Step 2. Catch variables values

In order to catch what's wrong, you can log some debug info and inspect it. For example, you can rewrite your `index()` a bit:

```
public function index() {
    $debug_me = 1;

    $raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json = json_decode($raw, true);

    if ($debug_me) {
        ob_start();
        var_dump('raw:', $raw, 'json:', $json);
        log_message('info', ob_get_contents());
        ob_end_clean();
    }

    //$uuid = $json["uuid"];

    //$this->email->from('Senders@email.com', 'Senders Name');
    //$this->email->to('Recievers@email.com'); 
    //$this->email->subject($uuid);
    //$this->email->message($uuid); 
    //$this->email->send(); 

}
```

Open log file. Now you can examine what is inside your `$raw` and `$json` variables. This is not the last step. Please, if you will debug, update your question with logged debug info, so we will try to find what is wrong with your script.

**To be continued...**

Comment: I modified my index function to your code, and ran the server callback from the 3rd party service.. But I don't have a `system/logs` folder anywhere..

Comment: I've updated answer. Also, I think I was wrong when I told about `system/logs`. Updated this too.

Comment: Ok, I did everything you said. I've updated the original question to show the logfile.. I don't see anything that has the $raw or $json variables?

Comment: Was `Process_video_test` called? As I see from logs, it was not called.

Comment: Yes it was called.. I can confirm this by looking at my server logs

Comment: I've added step 0 ))))

Comment: Ok thanks Sergey (I appreciate your help so much!).. 
I don't understand what to do now though.. When I goto this file (process_video_test) I get no 403.. Also, the dev from the 3rd party API gets a 200 response.. Any idea what could be blocking this server callback specifically?

Comment: Could you please get `process_video_test` by yourself and show both server and CodeIgniter logs for this http-200-like attempt?

Comment: Sergey- Because of your help I was able to track down the problem correctly. I was then able to take it to my webhost, whom informed me that: `Your application was hitting a mod security rule that I needed to whitelist. I also needed to turn on CURL and GET for your account.`

Thank You @Sergey Ronin-- my problem is solved!!

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to see this [Link](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html). Try logging your errors.

If you are POSTing the data then why use `$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');`? Simply take the data from the `post` like this:

```
$uuid = $this->input->post('uuid') //or $this->input->get('uuid'); try both once.
```

Comment: I apologize for my confusing terminology: I am not POSTing the data myself. It's being sent from within a 3rd party service.